# Reuse PyCharm Python virtual environment in Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, cygwin, virtualenv

I have created a PyCharm project containing several Python scripts, it's using virtual environment. All is set-up and it's up and running. Windows 10.

I would now like to run the same Python scripts from within Cygwin command line. Is there a way to reuse the virtual environment created by PyCharm (`C:\Users\joe_doe\\.virtualenvs\prj_name`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: no, I don't believe it is possible, and even if it were it is not worth the trouble.

Virtual environments should probably be considered as throwaway things. Use something like `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to save the list of projects installed in the virtual environment. And then `pip install --requirement requirements.txt` to install these projects in a new environment. It is a good habit to curate the list of requirements and one should be comfortable with deleting and recreating virtual environments on a whim without fear of losing any information.

Comment: @Danijel Does that answer your question?